# get average of last three entries for each user

Tags: mysql, database, average

I need a query that will show the average of the last three entries for each user, then display these averages from highest to lowest

I can extract this for a specific user using:

```
SELECT x.`cf_user_id` , AVG( x.`text_2` )
FROM 
(SELECT t.`cf_user_id` , t.`text_2`
FROM `jos_chronoforms_skills_drawback` t
WHERE t.`cf_user_id` = 62
ORDER BY t.`cf_id` DESC
LIMIT 3) x
GROUP BY x.`cf_user_id`
```

But I need this for each user.

Thanx a ton for your help

Mark

Comment: Take out your where clause, I doubt every user has an id of 62

Answer (score 0):

Your sql has a `WHERE` clause identifying a specific user.  If you want this for all users, remove your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT x.`cf_user_id` , AVG( x.`text_2` )
FROM 
(
    SELECT t.`cf_user_id` , t.`text_2`
    FROM `jos_chronoforms_skills_drawback` t
    ORDER BY t.`cf_id` DESC
    LIMIT 3
) x
GROUP BY x.`cf_user_id`
```